Simple ListView highlighted item is weird
I have written a simple IPTV app with two list views:
Screen Image

I have clicked on the first item (UK SPORT) from groups list view and the titles list view are populated (nothing highlighted on the titles).
I have clicked the 11th item and that row is highlighted correctly and played.
I have clicked an another group (e.g. UK ENTERTAINMENT) as shown in the picture, the titles are populated correctly but the highlighted item is weird (see above picture).

Layout of the two list views:
<ListView
    android:background="#AA202020"
        android:id="@+id/lv_groups"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="#EEFF0000"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

<ListView
        android:layout_marginLeft="215dp"
        android:background="#AA202020"
        android:id="@+id/lv_titles"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="#AAFF0000"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


Code:
lvGroups.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String grp = groups.get(position);
        populateTitles(grp);
    }
});

I expected the 1st row (RTE ONE HD) to be highlighted. The previous selected title highlighted item stays in a weird position.
